# Setting Property using only string name

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reflection

Is there a way I can set a property by identifying it using a string?

For example, I have a Visibility property that looks something like this:

```
public Visibility ModifyFilesIconVisibility
        {
            get { return modifyFilesIconVisibility; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref modifyFilesIconVisibility, value, () => ModifyFilesIconVisibility);
            }
        }
```

which is bound to an icon in XAML. Since each icon's visibility is set during runtime based on user authority to access each APIs, I have a Dictionary mapping:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> Views = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {
                        {
    "ModifyFiles", 
            new List<string>{"/editFile", "/deleteFile", "/cutFile", "/copyFile"}
        }, 
                        {
    "CRUDLogs", 
            new List<string>{"/writeLog", "/deleteLog", "/viewLog", "/searchLog"}
        },       
                        };
```

and if any of the APIs in the List is available in the authority (which I receive from an external API as well), I will modify the visibility of each icon. So for example, if /editFile is available to the user, the ModifyFilesIconVisibility will be set:

```
foreach (string api in APIMappings.Views["ModifyFiles"])
{
  if (URLs.Contains(api)) 
  {
   this.ModifyFilesIconVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
   break;
  }
}
```

Otherwise they are left as `Visibility.Collapsed`.

Since this is tedious, I was wondering if I can somehow use the name of the property itself in the mapping

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> Views = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {
                        {
    "ModifyFilesIconVisibility", 
            new List<string>{"/editFile", "/deleteFile", "/cutFile", "/copyFile"}
        }, 
                        {
    "CRUDLogsIconVisibility", 
            new List<string>{"/writeLog", "/deleteLog", "/viewLog", "/searchLog"}
        },       
                        };
```

or something like that, and then use the Dictionary key to set it to visible using reflection or anything else. Is this possible?

Comment: seems like you have bug in your `ModifyFilesIconVisibility` setter. The last parameter of SetValue method should be: () => **M**odifyFilesIconVisibility. Consider using [CallerMemberName](http://10rem.net/blog/2013/02/25/using-callermembername-for-property-change-notification-in-xaml-apps) attribute instead of lambda expression and [nameof](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/the-new-feature-of-C-Sharp-6-0-nameof-operator/) in C# 6:

Comment: @Liero hi Liero! Sorry about that, I typed that in to hide the real names of the functions. Thanks for the sharp eye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string propertyName = "ModifyFilesIconVisibility";

 var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this).Find(propertyName, false);
 property.SetValue(this, Visibility.Visible);
```

assuming `this` points to the instance with ModifyFilesIconVisibility property